# Как совместить два параметра URL в один?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Например, есть такой URL [image: url]

Я создаю его следующим образом:

```
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?from=" + "controller?command=go_to_make_bet&match=8");
```

Когда я напишу: `String parametr = request.getParameter("form");`

Мне выдаёт: `controller?command=go_to_make_bet`

А я хочу что бы выдало: `controller?command=go_to_make_bet&match=8`

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: стандартно заескейпить: `login.jsp?from=controller%3Fcommand=go_to_make_bet%26match=8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

символы `&`и `?` заменить на `url` коды.
ваша ссылка будет выглядеть так:

```
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?from=" + "controller%3Fcommand=go_to_make_bet%26match=8");
```

Answer (score -2):

Второй вопросительный знак лишний.
На выходе будет 3 параметра: from, command, match.

`response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?from=" + "controller&command=go_to_make_bet&match=8");`